# Formatting issue in XML with the elements with the same name at different levels

Tags: json

I'm getting the following format for my XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<n0:MT_NODE_CodingList xmlns:n0="cdcvvrvrv"> 
<DocumentId>78D6590F-2843-434D-AF0F-76B11680B6AD</DocumentId> 
<CodingLines> <CurrentDocumentLineReferenceId>00001</CurrentDocumentLineReferenceId> 
<LineID>00001</LineID> 
<UUID>3CA6E835-1F8F-4B7F-A255-FCBF766AE1C8</UUID> 
<Amount>7000000.00</Amount> 
<currencyID>USD</currencyID>
 <Quantity>100000.000</Quantity> 
<unitCode>KGM</unitCode> 
<Codes> <ID>purchasinggroup</ID> 
<Name>Reserve for Source</Name> 
<Value>530</Value> 
</Codes> </CodingLines> </n0:MT_NODE_CodingList>
```

I would like to convert the XML to the format below:

```
{"DocumentId":"41DCF8A4-6D05-4A8F-9265-F5E6BCD96CCF",
"CodingLines":{{"CodingLines":[{"ID":{"value":"177AFD35-5EF5-4466-88C6-B4755CC2E1A0"},
"OrderLineReference":[{"LineID":{"value":"00001"}}],
"CurrentDocumentLineReferenceId":"00001",
"Amount":{"value":"100.00 ",
"currencyID":"USD"},
"Quantity":{"value":"100.000 ",
"unitCode":"GIA"},"Codes":[{"ID":{"value":"purchasinggroup"},
"Name":{"value":"Reserve for Source"},
"Value":{"value":108}}]}]}}}
```

But when I do the conversion from the SAP Application I am getting XML with the format below:

```
{"DocumentId":"41DCF8A4-6D05-4A8F-9265-F5E6BCD96CCF",
"CodingLines":[{"CodingLines":[{"ID":{"value":"177AFD35-5EF5-4466-88C6-B4755CC2E1A0"},
"OrderLineReference":[{"LineID":{"value":"00001"}}],
"CurrentDocumentLineReferenceId":"00001",
"Amount":{"value":"100.00 ",
"currencyID":"USD"},
"Quantity":{"value":"100.000 ",
"unitCode":"GIA"},
"Codes":[{"ID":{"value":"purchasinggroup"},
"Name":{"value":"Reserve for Source"},
"Value":{"value":108}}]}]}]}
```

What do I have to do to make the first `CodingLines` start with '{' and the  CodingLines in the level below to have an array '['.